# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY error for ionic-paypal

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, paypal

I was trying to install paypal & onesignal plugin from official website with the help of official documentations and I got this error:

+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@4.3.2 
`-- @ionic-native/paypal@5.30.0

Here is my Package.json

{
"name": "ionic-hello-world",
"version": "0.0.0",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
"@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.30.0",
"@ionic-native/paypal": "^5.30.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"woocommerce-api": "^1.5.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
"typescript": "2.4.2"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"ionic-plugin-keyboard",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "ClickThrough: An Ionic project"
}

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal service used by ionic-native/paypal has been deprecated for years and is end of life on December 7.

---

You should instead integrate the [v2/checkout/orders API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/) from a server, with or without [the JS front end](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) for the approval flow.

Approval [requires](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications) a full mobile browser or SFSafariViewController/Chrome Custom Tabs. Approval cannot be given in a WKWebView or similar.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that.. but on the other side, I was trying to install OneSignal.. got the same error.

Comment: npm WARN @ionic-native/onesignal@5.30.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN @ionic-native/paypal@5.30.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none was installed.